# Best practice: in domain model use typeof with interface or use enum

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

What is the best practice for the next scenario (.net framework c#):

I have one object named Message.
This message has two types, Request and Response.

I can have a Message object with a reference to an enum "MessageType". There I can use the two types.

I don't like this solution; I would like to know if there is another solution, so if I will update the code in the future it will not break and will be easy for modifications.

Comment: Are request and response inheriting from message?

Comment: Show us some code. You say you don't like the solution you have currently, but *why* don't you like it?

Comment: i have a web service. i send to 3rd party a request containing Message object. i get from this 3rd party the same object as a response with different updated data. when i save the message object into the database i need to know if it is the response or request. i can use an enum, but i cwould like to know if i can use interface as well. then i can check the typeof and do some actions accordingly. communication is asynchrone

Comment: And just why would you create separate classes to represent nothing but a property.  Where would it stop?   If you had low and high priority would you split it out again?   Sure you can do it with TypeOf but why?

Comment: Why do you need to use typeof if you use interfaces?

Comment: Why not the usual iheritance? `abstract Message`, `ResponseMessage : Message`, `RequestMessage : Message` and `public ResponseMessage Send(RequestMessage message)` ? You absolutely will need a DTO to be converted from the original 3rd party webservice's `Message`. Explicit conversion can help too.